# SVG Marker Not Working

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've got a little issue with a marker that I can't seem to resolve.  The `marker-end` isn't rendering:

Here's the code responsible for defining the marker itself:

```
  this.svg.insert('defs', ':first-child')
    .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'arrow')
      .attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
      .attr('markerWidth', 12)
      .attr('markerHeight', 12)
      .attr('viewBox', '0 0 12 12')
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
    .append('path')
      .attr('d', 'M0, 0 V12 L12,12 Z');
```

Then here's where I render a line and reference the marker (the x/y coords of the line are set later).

```
  this.line = container.append('line')
    .classed('arc', true)
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');
```

And lastly LESS related to the marker and arc:

```
#arrow {
  stroke-fill: @light-gray;
  fill: @light-gray;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.arc {
  stroke: @light-gray;
  stroke-width: 4px;

  &:hover {
    stroke: @orange;
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'url(#arrow)'`, not `'url(marker#arrow)'`.

The value inside the `url()` is a URL, not a CSS selector!  In this case, it is a local URL fragment, which just happens to look like the equivalent selector.  However, if you were going to put anything before the `#`, it would be a full URL, like `url(http://example.com/myGraphic.svg#arrow)`.

Comment: I changed that with no luck :(, the `marker#arrow` was a desperate attempt at a fix.

Comment: Interesting, so, you indirectly got me to the answer!  The surrounding context is the issue.  I'm using AngularJS to build the UI.  The path to the page is `/free`, even though it's served from `/index.html` (HTML5 paths).  Accordingly adding `/free#marker` fixes the problem.

Comment: Interesting.  Are you directly modifying the base URL on your page?  Or is it that the marker code always stays in your template file, not copied to the destination?  Either way, it's an important gotcha to note fore other people using Angular + SVG.

Comment: Yea, we're using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` -- so routes just update the url path instead of the hash.

Comment: Of note, however, is that I'm still not sure why a local reference wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid this is outside my area of expertise; why don't you create a separate question in the Angular tag, linking back to this one, explaining the issue with local URL fragments?